# How do you know if a user has paid at affiliate website?

Tags: affiliate, skyscanner

I have a question about the way of affiliation commission in websites.
I understand that the websites like Skyscanner earn commission when their users have actually bought flight tickets at the flight company through their link.

The question is, how would Skyscanner knows whether the user actually has bought the ticket, or just exits the website in the middle before payment? Is it the information the affiliation website should provide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So when you click on the link provided in Skyscanner, this link will have an **Affiliated ID** which is given by the flight company. Using this ID, the flight company will give the commission to Skyscanner if the user has really made the purchase.

So yes it's the flight company that will provide data to Skyscanner if the user has made the purchase or not.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! By the way, is there no chance that the flight company might report the information wrongly? (so that they will pay for the commission lesser) I am just thinking that the information should be managed by both in order for it to be more transparent.

Comment: Once you click the link, the flight company has full control over it, you won't be knowing anything until they gives you the report. 
I think it's a matter of trust, but in case you see a discrepancy in orders, you can file a case.

Comment: I see. I understand what you say. That would be limit. Thank you a lot again!